# Drop Ethernet frames in an existing communication using BPF

Tags: linux, gstreamer, h.264, ebpf, bpf

Is it possible to apply Berkeley Packet Filter (BPF) to an existing socket communication of another application on a Ubuntu 20.04 system?
The goal is to intentionally introduce package losses in the kernel to reduce the workload of the application.

**long story:**

I have five IP cameras attached to a Ubuntu 20.04 PC.
These cameras send a h264 encoded image stream with fixed 30 FPS via RTP.
Now, I want to visualize all cameras using gstreamer at the same time, to have a nice little home surveillance system.
The gstreamer string for one camera is:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5550 caps="application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H264,payload=96" ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink sync=false async=false
```

However, if I visualize all cameras at the same time, the system load explodes.
Thus, my goal is to reduce the system load by reducing the images which need to be decoded.
Using gstreamer's [videorate](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/videorate/index.html?gi-language=c) is no option, because it can only be applied after the decoding step `avdec_h264`.
Also, the h264 stream coming from the camera only consists of I-frames (intra-compressed frames).
Therefore, the `skip-frame` from [avdec_h264](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/libav/avdec_h264.html?gi-language=c#avdec_h264-page) is no option.

Eventually I want to limit the I-frames before they reach the gstreamer application.
I thought of using BPF which drop ethernet frames based on the RTP package number.
I've already manually drop frames based on a PCAP recording and performed a successful replay with a reduced system load.

Now I want to perform this in a live system.
But how do I apply a packetfilter to another program's communication?

Answer (score 2):

Processes can only attach socket programs to sockets they own, so in this case the gstreamer would be able to do so, but not an external program.

You can still act on traffic in general by using a [TC program](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc-bpf.8.html), this will effect all traffic on the interface you will need to figure out which traffic you are targeting.

I have to say that this feels like a difficult route to lower frame-rate. No way to limit this at the source? I would expect that to be a setting somewhere in IP cameras

Comment: Unfortunately, the framerate cannot be reduced at the source. Those are actually some former vehicle cameras which I want to reuse. There exits no documentation nor open port or network service to configure them. The just start sending out the RTP stream when power is applied.

Comment: TC seems to be some part of the answer. While digging deeper, I've found this: [TUN/TAP driver does provide virtual network interface and it is possible
 to attach BPF to this interface.](http://vtun.sourceforge.net/tun/faq.html). Thus, I could filter while forwarding the communication from the NIC to a TUN. `gstreamer` listens on the TUN and the NIC is left unattached, right?

Comment: I am not 100% sure about TUN/TAP interfaces. But if you want to go that route, one thing I do know works is to create a virtual ethernet device https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/veth.4.html and connect to it. You can give the virtual device its own IP address and make the host forward traffic to it, if you use that device as dedicated for the streams, you can attach a TC program on the veth device and you don't have to worry about other traffic.